# Select more than one radio button that are mapped into different radio groups - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, material-ui

I am using react and have mapped some data into their own groupings. Once they have been mapped into a group I am then mapping the items into the group of which they came from.

**The problem** I am getting is I can still only choose one radio button in the entirety when I should be able to choose one from each group. I am using material-ui for `<Radio Group>`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/9lz7q7557w

Mapping the newly sorted keys(lodash) into a render:

```
      {data.length > 0 ?
        Object.keys(groups).map((item, index) => this.renderPlayerListItem(item, groups))
        :
        <div className="text-center">
          NO RESULTS
        </div>
      }
```

Then mapping the group items into the individual returns:

```
  <React.Fragment>
    <h2>{item}</h2>
    {groups[item].map((person, i) =>
      <RadioGroup
        aria-label="matches"
        name="matches"
        value={String(this.state.value)}
        style={{ display: 'block' }}
      >
        <FormControlLabel
          onClick={e => this.handlePlayerToggle(e)}
          checked={this.state.checked}
          key={String(person.Id)}
          value={String(person.Id)}
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label={
            <div>
              {person.firstName} {person.lastName}
            </div>
          }
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    )}
  </React.Fragment>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/9lz7q7557w - Something I put together as an example. Same outcome unfortunately. Any help would be appreciated. Welcome any alternatives to desired result if I have gone about it the wrong way.

UPDATE: I think the issue is the value. Each radio input has a value 1,2,3,4. I think it should be 1,2 and 1,2 in each group

Comment: HTML radio buttons are grouped via the `name` attribute. For each group, try using a different `name`.

Comment: Yes I tried that by calling name {groups} as this would name them all something different

Comment: Calling them name={item} gives a different name between the groups

Comment: 1,2 and 1,2 in each group will give you a problem of selecting 1 at a time from both groups or 2 at a time from both groups as per the current logic.

Comment: the problem here is the `value` in state is causing you to only set one at a time. You have to assign it or break this into each group having its own toggle state which fulfils the value for the each group selection. This is causing you to set only one toggle at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your sandbox, the issue is with the `state` variable as `value`. This value is always being set once and is not separated group wise. This single variable is controlling all the Radio toggle in all the groups. You have to separate each group in an independent component with independent toggle state. So your new component would look something like this:

```
class RadioGroupComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handlePlayerToggle = this.handlePlayerToggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      value : _.head(props.items).Id,
    }
  }
  handlePlayerToggle(e) {
    this.setState({ value : e.target.value })
  }
  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      {items.map(persons, person => (
        <RadioGroup
        aria-label="matches"
        name={groups}
        value={String(this.state.value)}
        style={{ display: "block" }}
      >
        <FormControlLabel
          onClick={e => this.handlePlayerToggle(e)}
          checked={this.state.checked}
          key={String(person.Id)}
          value={String(person.Id)}
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label={
            <div>
              {person.firstName} {person.lastName}
            </div>
          }
        />
          </RadioGroup>))}
        </React.Fragment>);
    }
  }
```

[lodash head](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#head) will help to set the first item selected by default in each group.
And now each group will have its one state to be set hence making each group function independently. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thankyou... I am struggling to get this into a workable. Could you use my codesandbox if poss? please!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/3x5nq972y6 I've done this based on the above. Nearly there but cant quite get it to work